# Load link src into iFrame from an asp.net MVC4 controllers action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

1. created a MVC4 ASP.NET application with razor view

--view code here - iframe and the form with 2 fields on it. Enter ID and click the Search button does invokes the Index Action of the HomeController

```
@model  BusinessApp.Models.SearchViewModel

<iframe id="photomural" name ="mural" src="http://www.mywebfind.com/search"     scrolling="yes" width ="75%"> </iframe>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Search </legend>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SomeID)
    </div>
    <div >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SomeID)
    </div>


    <p>
        <input name="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

-- based on the user values entered in the search box - the Index action of the home controller is executed.

-- based on some logic that is then executed in the action I would like to have the "src" of the Iframe to be loaded with the link to some website

--CODE in action Method of Home Controller to change the "src" of the IFrame. Could someone please give me some pointers.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel searchVM)
    {

        if (searchVM.SomeID != null)
        {
           //Execute some logic to determine the ID of the URL below that will be passed to Iframe


        }

         ???? Code to change the IFrame src to some url like   
       "http://OrderManagementSystem/ShowOrder.aspx?ID=10248"  based on above logic 
         return ???
    }
```

}

I appreciate any help I can get from any of the experts out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't find an answer anywhere.  Then realized I could set the target in the @using statement to the id of your iframe and return  your normal view.  Hope this helps someone!

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "photomural"} ))
```